# Original thumbs position when mouseleave scrolled thumbs div

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, mouseleave

I'm using this code http://jsbin.com/uninug/3/edit?html,css,js,output to do a thumbs slider.

I want to reset the inner thumbs div position to its original position when mouse "leave" (not hover) the container thumbs div, but I don't know much JavaScript (i'm a beginner). I'm trying this code but it just do nothing:

```
$bl.mouseleave (function() {
        $th.css({marginLeft: 0 });
    });
```

Any clue, tutorial or help are welcome.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in the script you are referring to has a timeout function that continuously asks for current position (given in local variables) and calculates the correct offset and margins based on that. Therefor your current javascript doesn't work - cause it will just be overruled by the timeout function that looks at the local variables for current position. Therefor you have to reset the position to `0`.

By adding a function like this:

```
$bl.mouseleave(function(e) {
    mX = 0;
    mX2 = 0;
});
```

http://jsbin.com/mecofesito/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Many thanks @Dimser your code works great and your explication helps me so much to understand what you do and what happens. I don't have the reputation to rate on SOF,  but your answer solve the code. Thanks!

Comment: @bluufoox You are more than welcome - and welcome to Stackoverflow. (Noticed you got yourself a username) This is truly a place that can help you become knowledgable in different aspects of development. Good luck.